Openssl build not working on M3 mac for arm64 simulator
I'm trying to build fat library for arm64 simulator, but it gives error that both device and simulator are having same architecture.
Using Xcode 15.4
I tried using lipo -create command
Is cocoapods the source of the problem?

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
